# Parse Logout 401 unauthorized using REST api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, parse-platform, ionic-framework

So, I'm trying to delete a Session object at Parse using the logout method calling the REST api.

Here is my code:

```
logout:function(data){
            return $http.post('https://api.parse.com/1/logout',{
                headers: {
                    'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
                    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
                    'X-Parse-Session-Token': data.sessionToken
                }
            });
        }
```

The variables are correct, I've inspected the request headers using devTools and both the credentials and session token are being set correctly but I'm still getting the response status 401,

```
{error: "unauthorized"}
```

I know the logout concept does not apply to REST services, still, it creates a Session object whenever I log in a user. To avoid thousands of left over Sessions in my Parse app, I am trying to make the logout function to destroy the Session.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue and this is what I've found so far -

Angular $http provider seems to require a data content for POST request

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Adding an empty data object solved this problem:

```
// define an empty object as required by $http
var mydata = {};
return $http.post(EXPRESSAPP.X_REST_API + 'logout', mydata, {
    headers:{
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
        'X-Parse-Session-Token': data.sessionToken
        }
});
```