# Parse REST api Logout 401 unauthorized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, rest, parse-platform

I am using the Parse REST API in my javascript app and struggling to get the logout function working.

I can login and signup users just fine but logging out throws an error 'POST https://api.parse.com/1/logout 401 (Unauthorized)'.

here is my code:

```
logout: function(user) {
  var config = {
    headers:{
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
        'X-Parse-Session-Token': user.sessionToken
    }
  };
  return $http.post('https://api.parse.com/1/logout', config);
}
```

I am successfully getting the current users sessionToken but it just doesn't seem to work.

Am I missing something here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've the exact same issue. Did you find a solution? Your code (and mine) actually works when posted directly ( with postman for example)...

Comment: Hi Seb, no I haven't found a solution yet but I've just see your answer so I'll give that a shot tomorrow. Seems strange that you have to pass it an empty object for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I just found the answer here:
[Parse Logout 401 unauthorized using REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090764/parse-logout-401-unauthorized-using-rest-api)

Just adding and empty data attribute worked for me as well! This is the code:

```
// define an empty object as required by $http
var mydata = {};
return $http.post(EXPRESSAPP.X_REST_API + 'logout', mydata, {
    headers:{
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
        'X-Parse-Session-Token': data.sessionToken
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi Seb, I tried this and it worked a treat. Thanks for the help mate.